# Why the code stopped unexpected when debugging?

Tags: c#

When i was debugging the code:

```
 void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //execute when the application closed 
            Application.Lock();
            Dictionary<string, VisitorUser> dic = new Dictionary<string, VisitorUser>();
            dic = (Dictionary<string, VisitorUser>)Application["MeetUsers"];
            if (dic != null)
            {
                StringBuilder sbVisitor = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, VisitorUser> key in dic)
                {
                    VisitorUser vu = key.Value;
                    sbVisitor.Append(" select '"+vu.UserName+"','"+vu.ImgUrl+"','"+vu.NickName+"',"+vu.LoginTime+" union ");
                }
                new VipUserBLL().BackUpVisitor(sbVisitor.ToString().Trim().Trim("union".ToCharArray()));
            }
            Application.UnLock();
        }
```

It stopped in:

StringBuilder sbVisitor = new StringBuilder();

and do not continue to execute.How could this happen what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it happen on the first or subsequent loops?

Is  `new VipUserBLL().BackUpVisitor..` an asynchronous call?

I don't know why it would happen but I would refactor your code like this:

```
try
{
    //execute when the application closed 
    Application.Lock();
    Dictionary<string, VisitorUser> dic = new Dictionary<string, VisitorUser>();
    dic = (Dictionary<string, VisitorUser>)Application["MeetUsers"];
    if (dic != null)
    {
        StringBuilder sbVisitor = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, VisitorUser> key in dic)
        {
            VisitorUser vu = key.Value;
            sbVisitor.Append(" select '" + vu.UserName + "','" + vu.ImgUrl + "','" + vu.NickName + "'," + vu.LoginTime + " union ");
        }
        new VipUserBLL().BackUpVisitor(sbVisitor.ToString().Trim().Trim("union".ToCharArray()));
    }
}
catch (Exception E)
{
    // log error, you can put a break point here when debugging.
}
finally
{
    Application.UnLock();
}
```